# I'm a Scientologist. Okay, that's "A." — what does “A” mean in this context why is it capitalized?

Tags: word-meaning

This is from the movie Central
Intelligence, where a bully after apologizing to his victims and saying that he has become a better person reveals that it was in fact a fake apology:

> Good God, you're dumb!
>
> Dumber than ever, I guess!
>
> And you, too, Calvin!
>
> Look at that stupid look on those two faces.
>
> "The Lord taught me to care."
>
> Unbelievable.
>
> I'm a Scientologist. Okay, that's "A."
>
> And thetan-free since 2003.
>
> Clear as s**t.

You can find a larger fragment here at the bottom (warning, there is some swearing): https://www.scripts.com/script.php?id=central_intelligence_5252&p=28

Comment: Maybe, he was going to say, And blah blah blah, that's B. As when we use A and B to present an argument.

Comment: Can you clarfiy who speaks which line.  It is very hard for me to understand this script. You could add names to each new line.

Comment: @JamesK it's the same guy, [the bully](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3SsvC_2wKI0) (Jason Bateman) who recites all those lines. Watching the clip it's much easier to understand what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

He stresses his foremost argument and prepares the listener for other (less important) reasons.

> **And** thetan-free since 2003. (That's B)

Often, to achieve a humorous effect, there is no B (even though the listener has been prepared for it), and argument A is not particularly sensible, which renders the speaker's reasoning funny/silly.